# RemoveEventListener : nil key supplied for property lookup

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I created a group, and added the following event listener that calls a function:

```
catinBalloon:addEventListener( "touch", catinBalloontouch)
```

Subsequently, I inserted two objects into the group catinBalloon and added the group to the table:

```
table.insert( catandBalloonTable, #catandBalloonTable+1, catinBalloon )
```

As part of another function I want loop through the table to remove the listener event.

```
for i = #catandBalloonTable, 1, -1 do
print_r(catandBalloonTable[i])
    catandBalloonTable[i]:removeEventListener( "touch", catinBalloontouch) 

end
```

The output of the print_r before the error is:

```
04:20:03.364  table: 0DACC088 {
04:20:03.364    [_proxy] => userdata: 0DAD20E0
04:20:03.364    [_functionListeners] => table: 0DACC088 {
04:20:03.364                              [touch] => table: 0DADA0C0 {
04:20:03.364                                           [1] => function: 04080198
04:20:03.364                                           [2] => function: 0DA0E6E0
04:20:03.364                                         }
04:20:03.364                            }
04:20:03.364    [activeObjectWord] => "ant"
04:20:03.364    [_class] => table: 0DACC088 {
04:20:03.364                  [removeEventListener] => function: 04245CE8
04:20:03.364                  [addEventListener] => function: 04247968
04:20:03.364                  [__index] => table: 0425AE40 {
04:20:03.364                                 *table: 0425AE40
04:20:03.364                               }
04:20:03.364                }
04:20:03.364    [removeSelf] => function: 0433B9B8
04:20:03.364    [active] => "yes"
04:20:03.364    [activeObjectSound] => userdata: 0A0CAAE0
04:20:03.364  }
```

And the error is:

```
04:20:03.364  ERROR: nil key supplied for property lookup.
04:20:03.364  stack traceback:
04:20:03.364    [C]: ?
04:20:03.364    ?: in function 'removeEventListener'
04:20:03.364    ?: in function 'removeEventListener'
04:20:03.364    ?: in function 'removeEventListener'
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error when the handler function that you provided (`catinBalloontouch`) doesn't exist in this scope. One way to solve your problem is use forward reference.

```
-- top of your file
local catinBalloontouch 
...
function catinBalloontouch( event ) -- now you don't need use key word local
    ...
end
...
for i = #catandBalloonTable, 1, -1 do
print_r(catandBalloonTable[i])
    catandBalloonTable[i]:removeEventListener( "touch", catinBalloontouch) 

end
```